# Button click event not firing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('btnDelete1').click(function () {
        alert("something");
    })
});
```

And this is the code for the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete Role" disabled="disabled" id="btnDelete1"/>
```

But whenever I click the button, the alert isn't happening. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

The problem isn't connected with MVC anyway, you missed `#` in Jquery selector only.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnDelete1').click(function () {
        alert("something");
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

And as mentioned Jeffrey, you forget `;` too

Comment: I believe semicolons are optional in every major Javascript interpreter. The only time I've run into problems with omitting them is when I want to compress my JS, as some poorly written compressors require them.

Comment: Optional  semicolons are the main reason website crashing in old browsers(IE 6,7 ...)

Comment: Nope, they're optional in even IE6/7. Now trailing commas on the other hand completely destroy IE...

Comment: Oh, maybe... I will check it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is wrong

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnDelete1').click(function () {
        alert("something");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget a `;`?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnDelete1').click(function () {
        alert("something");
    });
});
```

Comment: After closing `click()`, behind the `})`.