# JQuery click of input button not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked on the forum and my question is a duplicate of [Button click event not firing in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880389/button-click-event-not-firing-in-jquery), except my code already matches the given answer.

I've stripped this down for you guys anyway, and can confirm that links with a class of disabled do not fire, so this proves the document ready and Jquery library are correct.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Prevents links from firing
  $('a.disabled').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Handles search
  $("#btnTreeSearch").click(function () {
    alert("click search fool!");
  });
});
```

Html

```
<input type="submit" value="btnTreeSearch" />
```

Any clues?

Comment: Your input doesn't have the id you are referencing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign `id` to input to use [**id selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ypuwQ/)**

*Html*

```
<input type="submit" id="btnTreeSearch" value="btnTreeSearch" />
```

*Javascript*

```
 $("#btnTreeSearch").click(function () {
     alert("click search!");
 });
```

Comment: Oops, just i just relaised what an idiot i am. I raced back here but wasn't as quick as you. The end of a long day!

Answer (score 1):

Change `value="btnTreeSearch"` to `id="btnTreeSearch"`.

Comment: Oops, just i just realised what an idiot i am. I raced back here but wasn't as quick as you. The end of a long day!